# Keras installed but not working

Tags: windows, python-2.7, scipy, keras, theano

I am using keras with theano as the back end to build a neural network on windows 10. My python version is 2.7. The problem is that when I try and use keras I keep getting a path error.

```
$python
>>import keras
```

Gives me the error

```
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
"g++" -shared -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -I"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Python27\include" -I"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof" -L"C:\Python27\libs" -L"C:\Python27" -o C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-Intel64_Family_6_Model_61_Stepping_4_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.14393-Intel64_Family_6_Model_61_Stepping_4_GenuineIntel-2.7.11-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -lpython27
The system cannot find the path specified.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras-2.0.3-py2.7.egg\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras-2.0.3-py2.7.egg\keras\activations.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import backend as K
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras-2.0.3-py2.7.egg\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from .theano_backend import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras-2.0.3-py2.7.egg\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 3, in <module>
    import theano
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg\theano\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 21, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\mode.py", line 10, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\vm.py", line 662, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano-0.9.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2316, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
. ception: Compilation failed (return status=1): The system cannot find the path specified.
>>>
```

I can tell that I need to add to my system variables paths (at least I think so...) but no matter what I add I still get the error. I have tried adding

```
C:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
```

Basically any of the paths it said could not be specified.  Something to note would be that I had a lot of trouble getting scipy installed and had to get the .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy not sure if that helps at all.  Well that's my issue.

Comment: it probably cannot find g++, do you have it installed and where? is that path in the PATH?

Comment: If you don't have g++ installed, try MinGW - I found mine here: https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and resolved with removing other python versions. Make sure that you have only 1 python installed. If there is multiple, thing sometimes don't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is use keras in a separate environment using conda.
Suppose you want to create an env named "myenv" 
1.Open Anaconda promt and type the following:

```
conda create --name myenv
```

2.To activate the environment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

3.Now you can install keras and other dependencies:

```
pip install keras
```

Install tensorflow as follows.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```